# iFrame Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a game and unblocked sites site with a chat system, I have come across a problem with an iframe. I added TikTok as one of sites in an iframe with a source as https://generalmathematics.net/service/hvtrs8%2F-wuw%2Ctkkvoi.aoo%2F. When I open the iframe I get an error saying, "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()". I am using glitch.com which host your site and gives you a domain for free.

```html
 <h1>
  TikTok
 </h1>
 <iframe src="https://generalmathematics.net/service/hvtrs8%2F-wuw%2Ctkkvoi.aoo%2F">
 </iframe>
```

Comment: Hitting that link directly also generates a 404 error. Therefore the link is inccorect.

Comment: The link loads TikTok for me?

Comment: @JonP the link doesn't show a 404 error for me.